# "self" object has no attribute to "draw" and much more(pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I know there are many answers on "hmm" has no attribute to "hmm". But I think that I have more errors than that and I am not in such a situation as the others. The following error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python33/Pong(bong).py", line 144, in <module>
 self.draw(Rect)
 AttributeError: 'self' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

And the code itself is very long. I have tried to find a solution and I didn't find anything. Well, now the important:

```py
import pygame
import os
img_path = os.path.join('C:\Python33', 'bongstick.png')
img_path_two = os.path.join('C:\Python33', 'bongball.png')

class self(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 30
        self.y = 30
        self.image = img_path
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 20, 60)

    def key(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 1
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= dist
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += dist

class ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(ball):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(ball)
        ball.x = 350
        ball.y = 350
        ball.image = img_path_two
        ball.rect = pygame.Rect(ball.x, ball.y, 20, 20)

    def movement(ball):
        dist = 1
        flyalittleleft = False
        flyalittleright = False
        flyalittledownleft = True
        flyalittledownright = False
        right = False
        left = False
        if ball.y < 670 and right == True:
            flyalittleleft = True
        if flyalittleleft == True:
            ball.y -= dist
            ball.x -= dist
            right = True
            flyalittleright = True
            flyalittleleft = False
            flyalittledownleft = False
            flyalittledownright = False
        if ball.y < 670 and left == True:
            flyalittleright = True
        if flyalittleright == True:
            ball.y -= dist
            ball.x += dist
            flyalittleleft = True
            left = True
            flyalittleright = False
            flyalittledownright = False
            flyalittledownleft = False
        if ball.y < 10 and right:
            flyalittledownleft = True
        if flyalittledownleft == True:
            ball.x -= dist
            ball.y += dist
            right = True
            flyalittleleft = False
            flyalittleright = False
            flyalittledownleft = False
            flyalittledownright = True
        if left == True:
            pass
        else:
            flyalittledownleft = False
            flyalittleleft = False
        if right == True:
            pass
        else:
            flyalittledownright = False
            flyalittleright = False
        if ball.y < 10 and left == True:
            flyalittledownright = True
        if flyalittledownright == True:
            ball.y += dist
            ball.x -= dist
            flyalittledonwleft = False
            flyalittelright = False
            flyalittleleft = False
        if ball.colliderect(self) and flyalittleleft == True:
            flyallitelright = True
            flyalittleleft = False
            flyalittledonwleft = False
            flyalittledownright = False
        if ball.colliderect(self) and  flyalittledownleft == True:
            flyalittledownright = True
            flyalittledonwleft = False
            flyalittleleft = False
            flyalittleright = False
        if ball.colliderect(bongsticktwo) and flyalittleright == True:
            flyalittleright = False
            flyalittleleft = True
            flyalittledownleft = False
            flyalittledownright = False
        if ball.colliderect(bongsticktwo) and flyalittledownright == True:
            flyalittledownleft = True
            flyalittledownright = False
            flyalittleleft = False
            flyalittleright = True

class bongsticktwo(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(bongsticktwo):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(bongsticktwo)
        bongsticktwo.x = 670
        bongsticktwo.y = 670
        bongsticktwo.image = img_path
        bongsticktwo.rect = bongsticktwo.Rect(bongsticktwo.x, bongsticktwo.y, 20, 60)

    def movement(bongsticktwo):
        dist = 1
        flyup = True
        flydown = False
        if bongsticktwo.y < 10:
            flydown = True
        if flydown == True:
            bongsticktwo.y += dist
            flyup = False
        if bongsticktwo.y < 670:
            flyup = True
        if flyup == True:
            bongsticktwo.y -= dist
            flydown = False

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 700))
self = self()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    self.draw(Rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(60)
```

And it was hard to do some research because my solutions are a bit different than others, which means no good solutions. So I don't think there is some better solution than yours. And there were a couple of errors before to.

Sorry for my bad English. I'm from Sweden.
And if I remove `self.draw`, then there is just going to be some other error.

Comment: I think by naming your class `self` and another variable `self` you're just asking for confusing problems. It would be clearer if you only used `self` for the first argument to methods.

Comment: Understod. I didn't think i needed to do that.

Comment: Python doesn't have separate namespaces for variables, methods, and classes, like some other languages do. So when you set `self` to refer to something in a scope, you're losing the ability, in that scope, to refer to the other thing `self` referred to before. I don't see why your code doesn't work, but I also don't see any good reason to name those different things with the same name. The code will be clearer if you rename some of them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because you have a separate class called `self` which does not have an attribute `draw`, so Python is getting mixed up with the class called `self` and the instance of the object called `self`